# how to save a file outside the docker container with python

Tags: python, docker, docker-volume

So I have this structure:

myapp

- Dockerfile
- main.py
- req.txt

this is the content of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install -r req.txt
RUN playwright install
RUN playwright install-deps

CMD ["python", "./main.py"]
```

and on my main.py, eventually, I have this code

```
 current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
 result_path = os.path.join(current_path, 'result.json')

 with open(result_path, 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(result, json_file, indent=4)
```

I can see that the script is running successfully, but I can't see the file that was supposed to be created in the same folder, I understand that the file is being created at

> /app/results.json

but there's a way for this file to be created outside the container?

EDIT:
I have done my build with:

```
docker build -t myapp .
```

and I run like this:

```
docker run myapp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far so good, the way you are running app is perfectly alright.

So in Docker to save files on host's file system theres is a concept called mounting the volume from which file or directory of host can be directly mounted to your running container.

So right now I do not know where you want that file to be written on host. but the general command will be like this:

`docker run -v app:/app -it myapp`

This mounts app folder of your host to app folder in the container

More read on the same topic:
https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#start-a-container-with-a-bind-mount) at docker run:

```
docker run -v /path/to/host_app_dir:/app  myapp
```

This will bind two directories: the `/path/to/host_app_dir` in your host system and the `/app` folder inside docker. Any file written to `/app` will appear in `/path/to/host_app_dir`. They are essentially the same folder on your hard disk. That is the magic of bind mount.

Be careful, because you copy something into the /app folder (`COPY . /app`) during docker build. The content of /app will be replaced by the content of your host folder using the bind mount option above. See the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#mount-into-a-non-empty-directory-on-the-container).

I suggest that you use a different folder instead of `/app` to share files between the host and container.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount bind a folder on your machine to a folder inside the container with the-v option.
Files created inside this folder are then outside of the container.